# about the parameter in the RVineMLE

Tags: r, mle

When I use RvineMLE(){VineCopula}, I get the following system feedback.

```
$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

It reports an error when importing into rvinematrix(), showing.

```
In RVineMatrix: The parameter of the Frank copula has to be unequal to 0.
```

I'm not sure why the parameter of the Frank copula is 0 and  whether it's related to the message above.

```
RVM<-RVineStructureSelect(copula_data1,c(1:6),progress = TRUE,rotations = FALSE)
RVM1<-RVineCopSelect(copula_data1,familyset=c(1:6),RVM$Matrix,rotations = FALSE)
RVM2<-RVineSeqEst(copula_data1,RVM1) 
mle<-RVineMLE(copula_data1,RVM1)
vine_matrix<-RVineMatrix(mle$RVM$Matrix,family =mle$RVM$family,names=mle$RVM$names,par2 =mle$RVM$par2 )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved and details are available on the website at https://github.com/tnagler/VineCopula/issues/83

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.